# Sleep thread until another thread completes for iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, sleep, backend, amazon-dynamodb

I'm very new to backend programming and iOS programming. I'm currently integrating DynamoDB into my iOS application. I'm doing a signup function that queries the database to check whether the username is taken.

Here's the main idea of my code:

```
__block BOOL isPlayerTaken = NO;

//Block of code that queries the database
//Mutates value of isPlayerTaken if player exists

    [[dynamoDBObjectMapper query:[DDBRunnerTableRow class]
                  expression:queryExpression]
 continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
     AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
     DDBRunnerTableRow *queriedRunner = paginatedOutput.items[0];
     if (queriedRunner) {
         isPlayerTaken = YES;
         NSLog(@"%@", queriedRunner.runnerName);
     }

     return nil;
 }];


return isPlayerTaken;
```

However, the function returns before the query result is completed and hence the output is always NO.
How can I ensure that the function doesn't return until the query block completes?

Thank you so much for your help. I believe I would need this in many functions of my code that requires querying and inserting of data and I didn't want to come up with a hackish solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
[[dynamoDBObjectMapper query:[DDBRunnerTableRow class]
                  expression:queryExpression]
 continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
     AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
     DDBRunnerTableRow *queriedRunner = paginatedOutput.items[0];
     if (queriedRunner) 
     {
         NSLog(@"%@", queriedRunner.runnerName);
         [self loginSuccessfull:queriedRunner];
     }
     else 
     {
         [self loginFailed];
     }
 }];
```

then

```
- (void)loginSuccessfull:(DDBRunnerTableRow *)queriedRunner
{
    //whatever
}

- (void)loginFailed
{
    //whatever
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks alot for your quick response. Those code is actually in a function that serves to act as an abstraction to those backend API. 

Hence, I'm not planning to return or do something within the success block, but to return a value as an entire function itself. 

I'm thinking whether it'll be possible to add sleep function to block thread and a callback function to check whether query has completed.